# Still getting 413 Request Entity Too Large even after client_max_body_size 100M

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, digital-ocean

I'm using Rails and Nginx on Digital ocean and I've been trying to upload a 17.6 MB file and I'm still getting `413 Request Entity Too Large` even after setting `client_max_body_size 100M` in my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file.

Here's the snippet from the file:

```
http {

  ##
  # Basic Settings
  ##

  client_max_body_size 100M;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  ...
}
```

After setting this I've used `sudo service nginx reload`. When that didn't work I've even done a full reboot using `sudo shutdown -r now` and then `cap production puma:start` from my local machine. I've also tried `client_max_body_size 0;` which, from what I understand should disable checking of file sizes entirely. Nothing works. Plus, in getting to this point, I've made some mistakes in the location of the `client_max_body_size` statement and in those situations the server has failed to start correctly giving a "Something went wrong" error, so I'm pretty sure the changes I'm making are to the right file.

Is there something I might be missing? Is there another place I'm missing to configure this? Is there something I'm missing in the way I'm currently configuring it? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Okay. I figured this out. Following the Digital Ocean guide for [how to configure nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-nginx-web-server-on-a-virtual-private-server), I was setting `client_max_body_size 100M` in the file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. And for sure, changing things there definitely had impact on what the server did. Especially when I would mess something up in that file and the server stopped functioning.

However, I had forgotten that in [Deploying a Rails App on Ubuntu 14.04 with Capistrano, Nginx, and Puma](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma) which was my main resource for setting up my server, it shows that these parameters get set up not in the above `nginx.conf` but rather in my rails app there is the file `~/my_app/config/nginx.conf` in which the setup parameters already included the statement

```
  client_max_body_size 10M;
```

So I changed that statement as well as in the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file on production. Voila! Now I can upload files up to 100M.

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't have `nginx.conf` in my config directory of Rails application! Do you have any idea?

Comment: @AboozarRajabi not sure. Perhaps you could search your project for `client_max_body_size` and see if it might be somewhere else?

Comment: @tobogranyte It's not in my project files but on the server that I deployed my app using nginx.