# nginx + unicorn Entity is to large

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, unicorn

On my test server I have nginx + unicorn set up. And nginx `client_max_body_size` is set to `20M`. But she user uploads file more then 1mb it return error `413 Entity is too large. nginx`.

So, I don't quite understand what make this problem?

Is there any possibly to unicorn limit upload?

**EDIT**

I'am getting 500 error when user send POST method request (specifically large).

Comment: I think this is off-topic for Stack Overflow and would fit better on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Where, exactly, are you setting `client_max_body_size`?  Per [this StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781508/still-getting-413-request-entity-too-large-even-after-client-max-body-size-100m), it could be that that settings needs to appear in _other_ `nginx` config files.

Comment: `server { client_max_body_size 20m; }`. File is located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/my_site` (it's included in main nginx settings file)